# How to change duration of ImageView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, imageview, avfoundation

I am creating a simple camera app for a photobooth. This code below is a sample of the whole project, I am using AVFoundation because I needed my own custom requirements.

When the user presses a button, it takes a photo and instantly shows the preview in the imageView. This is my first major coding project and am new to Objective-C. Is there a way to add a timer or duration to the imageView so that it then removes the image from it, or a way to cycle to a second black image after some time, ready for the next user to take their photo?

Many thanks for any help suggested!

```
- (IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender {

    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in StillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts ]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [StillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            imageView.image = image;
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `dispatch_after` or `NSTimer` to do that.

dispatch_after:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do something
});
```

NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<#delayInSeconds#> target:self selector:@selector(action) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)action {
    // do something
}
```

`NSTimer` allows you to repeat the action if you want, but if you simply need to swap an image, `dispatch_after` is easier because you can do it in scope.

```
[StillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        imageView.image = image;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           imageView.image = imageToSwap;
        }
    }
}];
```